# mclapply with big objects - "serialization is too large to store in a raw vector"

Tags: r, multicore

I keep hitting an issue with the `multicore` package and big objects. The basic idea is that I'm using a Bioconductor function (`readBamGappedAlignments`) to read in large objects. I have a character vector of filenames, and I've been using `mclapply` to loop over the files and read them into a list. The function looks something like this:

```
objects <- mclapply(files, function(x) {
  on.exit(message(sprintf("Completed: %s", x)))
  message(sprintf("Started: '%s'", x))
  readBamGappedAlignments(x)
}, mc.cores=10)
```

However, I keep getting the following error: `Error: serialization is too large to store in a raw vector`. However, it seems I can read the same files in alone without this error. I've found mention of this issue [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-hpc/2010-August/000708.html), without resolution.

Any parallel solution suggestions would be appreciated - this has to be done in parallel. I could look towards snow, but I have a very powerful server with 15 processors, 8 cores each and 256GB of memory I can do this on. I rather just do it on this machine across cores, rather than using one of our clusters.

Comment: You can use socket clusters with snow on one machine ('localhost' is the default).

Comment: The error occurs because the data is converted to a vector of type raw when the parent tries to retrieve the data from the child, and the vector is longer than R's longest vector 2^31 - 1. Try moving more work insides the function, so the result is a 'reduction' of the big data.

Comment: Thanks a ton Martin! I suspected it could be related to this, but thought it would manifest in another error message. The lack of usage of `R_len_t` rearing it's ugly head again... it would be great if we could just set this to long and be done with it.

Comment: You might switch to using `foreach` instead, though I'm not entirely clear on where the long vector occurs.  If nothing else, you could also partition the objects in such a way to map a long vector to a matrix, by splitting every, say, 2^30 items into a new column.

Comment: can you traceback the error so that we can know the exact place it occurs?

Comment: Maybe Martin should move his comment to an answer? It is probably as good as advice as is possible with the info we have.

Answer (score 3):

The integer limit is rumored to be addressed very soon in R. In my experience that limit can block datasets with under 2 billion cells (around the maximum integer), and low level functions like `sendMaster` in the `multicore` package rely on passing raw vectors. I had around 1 million processes representing about 400 million rows of data and 800 million cells in the data.table format, and when mclapply was sending the results back it ran into this limit.

A divide and conquer strategy is not that hard and it works. I realize this is a hack and one should be able to rely on mclapply.

Instead of one big list, create a list of lists. Each sub-list is smaller than the broken version, and you then feed them into mclapply split by split. Call this `file_map`. The results are a list of lists, so you could then use the special double concatenate `do.call` function. As a result, each time mclapply finishes the size of the serialized raw vector is of a manageable size.

Just loop over the smaller pieces:

```
collector = vector("list", length(file_map)) # more complex than normal for speed 

for(index in 1:length(file_map)) {
reduced_set <- mclapply(file_map[[index]], function(x) {
      on.exit(message(sprintf("Completed: %s", x)))
      message(sprintf("Started: '%s'", x))
      readBamGappedAlignments(x)
    }, mc.cores=10)
collector[[index]]= reduced_set

}

output = do.call("c",do.call('c', collector)) # double concatenate of the list of lists
```

Alternately, save the output to a database as you go such as SQLite.