# How to debug/resolve "serialization is too large to store in raw vector" error when using Rmpi

Tags: r, parallel-processing, apply

I am running an analysis on my university's Unix cluster using R with the parallel processing tools in Rmpi. When I run the R script shown below on my local (Windows) machine using the snow package or just the standard apply function it is terribly slow but seems to work fine. When I run it on the Unix cluster using Rmpi I get an error "serialization too large to store in a raw vector." This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775064/mclapply-with-big-objects-serialization-is-too-large-to-store-in-a-raw-vector) seems on point, but the vectors I am passing back and forth (50K) shouldn't come close to triggering this error. Moreover, I can get things to partially work by dividing my data into smaller pieces. I think the problem must be some kind of memory leak associated with Rmpi, but I have none of the tools necessary for debugging such a thing. Hopefully you can at least point me in the direction of the tools for debugging what is going on here.

The data I am working with have ~2.5 million records, each record has ~40 columns. I submit a 50K x 40 data frame to parApply and it returns a 50K numeric vector.

```
#In an effort to avoid the serialization error I break into smaller pieces to avoid    
#problems with large vectors getting transferred between master and slave nodes
numBreaks<-floor(length(data[,1])/50000)
base<-min(length(data[,1]),50000)  #test data sets are < 50K and shouldn't 
                                   #crash the function    piece.in<-data[c(1:base),]         #this is the first batch of records I submit

status<-mpi.parApply(piece.in,1,test) #returns a vector of length 50K
#status<-apply(piece.in,1,test)   #commented out, function runs fine locally using                 
                                  #standard apply function
#cl <- makeSOCKcluster(c("localhost","localhost","localhost","localhost","localhost"))
#status<-parApply(cl,piece.in,1,test) #commented out, function runs fine locally
                                      #using snow's SOCK cluster and identical
                                      #parApply function
if(numBreaks>1){
for (i in 2:numBreaks){
  piece.in<-data[c((base+1):(base+50000)),]
  piece.out<-mpi.parApply(piece.in,1,test)  #returns a vector of length 50K

 #piece.out<-apply(piece.in,1,test)
 #piece.out<-parApply(cl,piece.in,1,test)
  status<-append(status,piece.out)          #add to existing vector
  base<-base+50000                          #increment base
  print(paste("clusters assigned to records",base,"through",(base+50000)))
 }
}

#This piece cleans up the residual records 
if((length(c(base:length(data[,1])))>1) & (base < length(data[,1]))){
  piece.in<-data[c((base+1):length(data[,1])),]
  #piece.out<-apply(piece.in,1,test)
  piece.out<-mpi.parApply(piece.in,1,test)
  #piece.out<-parApply(cl,piece.in,1,test)
  status<-append(status,piece.out)
  print(paste("Final: status has length",length(status)))
 }
```

This function works as intended on test datasets (~100K records). It works locally using snow or the standard apply function (though it takes a day). It failed with the "serialization too large..." error before I broke it into smaller pieces. It failed with the same error when I made the pieces 100K records long. It runs successfully (as documented by print statements written to file) all the way up to the iteration covering records 1.3 million to 1.35 million with the records being submitted in batches of 50K and then fails with the serialization error.

I know there are other ways of doing parallel processing, (and the foreach command is something I wish I was using here) but I am constrained by not knowing anything about the computing environment in which the parallel nodes are created so I would like to stay with Rmpi if I can. Any tips as to how to debug this?

Much obliged.

Chris

Comment: Do you have a rough estimation of how much memory do 100K records take? Is it anywhere near 2 GiB?

Comment: Not sure how to measure data frame size in bytes. It could potentially be large, but it doesn't make sense that it could loop through the 50K record loop 25 times before hitting an error unless some part of what it is doing is growing in size.

Comment: Not sure how it packs the data, but the `MPI_Pack` routine in MPI-2.2 has an offset argument of type `int`, which limits the buffer size to 2 GiB, even on 64-bit machines. 100K records x 40 columns are 4M fields. If the average field size is ~500 bytes, you already hit the limit.